# Split Lists into Sublists, List.Contains() does not find match

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I have 2 Lists, `Planets` and `Favorites`. They contain multiple words separated by spaces.

I split the Lists by space into Sublists.

Now I want to check if `Planets` contains a Name from `Favorites`.

But `Planets.Contains()` does not find a match.

http://rextester.com/YLOG10363

```
// Planets List
//
List<string> Planets = new List<string>();
Planets.Add("First Mercury Gray");
Planets.Add("Second Venus Yellow");
Planets.Add("Third Earth Blue");
Planets.Add("Fourth Mars Red");

// Favorites List
//
List<string> Favorites = new List<string>();
Favorites.Add("Venus Hot");
Favorites.Add("Mars Cold");

// Sublists
//
string[] arrPlanets = null;
string[] arrFavorites = null;
List<string> Order = new List<string>();
List<string> Names = new List<string>();
List<string> Colors = new List<string>();



// In each Line of Planets & Favorites Lists, Split by Space
// Add Word to it's Sublist
//
for (int i = 0; i < Planets.Count; i++)
{
    // Create Planet Sublists
    arrPlanets = Convert.ToString(Planets[i]).Split(' ');
    Order.Add(arrPlanets[0]);
    Names.Add(arrPlanets[1]);
    Colors.Add(arrPlanets[2]);

    // Create Favorites Sublist
    // Prevent Favorites index from going out of range
    if (i < Favorites.Count())
    {
        arrFavorites = Convert.ToString(Favorites[i]).Split(' ');

        // Display Message if Planets List Contains a Name from Favorites
        //
        if (Planets.Contains(arrFavorites[0]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Favorite Detected.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Convert.ToString` on a string?  Also I recommend you parse those values into classes that contain the 3 properties and then work with a list of that class type.

Comment: `public class Planet { public string Order { set; get; } public string Name { set; get; } public string Color { set; get; } }`

Comment: @juharr I had got an error that said it couldn't convert char to string. But after refactoring it seems to compile without having to do that.

Comment: @juharr I think I've found the problem area, `Contains` wont find a match in any List if it has any spaces separating words.

Comment: The problem is that `Planets` does not contain an exact string match.  What you want is `Planets.Any(p => p.Contains(arrFavorites[0]));` but that's really not a great idea.  If you had a `Planet` class it would be `Planets.Any(p => p.Name = arrFavorites[0]));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've looked at all the answers, and you might want to look at this possibility as well, since it represents the smallest amount of refactoring to your code:

Replace

```
if (Planets.Contains(arrFavorites[0]))
```

With

```
if (Planets.Any(p => p.Contains(arrFavorites[0])))
```

Not the most performant, since there are better algorithms to do checks for matching terms. But looking at your code, it doesn't seem like the most important thing that you're after. So possibly, my approach might make sense, then.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

It really isn't very clear what you are trying to accomplish, but since you said you want to find out if `Planets` contains any name from `Favorites`, and assuming the name is always the first word in each favorite,

```
var PlanetsHasFavorite = Planets.Any(p => Favorites.Select(f => f.Split(' ')[0]).Any(f => p.Split(' ').Contains(f)));
```

`PlanetsHasFavorite` will be true if any Planet matches a name from `Favorites`.

Assuming you meant you actually want to get a list of the matching planets,

```
var PlanetsAreFavorite = Planets.Where(p => Favorites.Select(f => f.Split(' ')[0]).Any(f => p.Split(' ').Contains(f))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if any word in any Favorite is contained in any Planet, then you only need to split the Favorites into words, and then see if any planet contains any word.

So, to get all the Favorite words, we can do something like this:

```
var favoriteWords = Favorites.SelectMany(i => i.Split(' '));
```

Now, we can loop through all the planets and see if we have any matches:

```
Planets.ForEach(p =>
{
    if (favoriteWords.Any(p.Contains))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"One of your favorite planets is: {p}");
    }
});
```

And the result is:

[image]

Or, if you just wanted to show the favorite words that were matched, you could do something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("These favorite words were matched: ");
Planets.ForEach(p => favoriteWords.Where(p.Contains).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use arrays if you don't know the number of items you want them to hold and DON'T  knowingly set variables to null.
Use Lists instead:

```
List<string> planets = new List<string>();
List<string> favorites = new List<string>();
```

That being said your code is totally wrong.
What you are trying to achieve is something like this:

```
List<string> Planets = new List<string>();
Planets.Add("First Mercury Gray");
Planets.Add("Second Venus Yellow");
Planets.Add("Third Earth Blue");
Planets.Add("Fourth Mars Red");

List<string> Favorites = new List<string>();
Favorites.Add("Venus Hot");
Favorites.Add("Mars Cold");

// Unless you need favorites to hold tokens seperated by a white space
// you shouldn't make another list such as this one:
List<string> faveKeywords = Favorites.SelectMany(fave => fave.Split(' ')).ToList();
foreach (var token in from line in Planets from token in line.Split(' ') where faveKeywords.Contains(token) select token)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Favorite detected: {token}" );
}
```

Or if you keep insisting on making that Order, Color, Name:

```
foreach (var tokens in Planets.Select(str => str.Split(' ')))
{
    Order.Add(tokens[0]);
    Names.Add(tokens[1]);
    Colors.Add(tokens[2]);
    foreach (var token in tokens.Where(token => faveKeywords.Contains(token)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Favorite detected: {token}");
    }
}
```

You need to learn from examples such as this one and observe more than you ask.

Comment: The only issue that I'd have is, that `List<T>` is less performant that a straightforward array. But the difference really comes to light under load pressure. **Bottom line: there are no rule of thumbs**. Just a requirement to understand what the technical trade-offs are. Understanding what the technical costs and benefits are, is the key, rather than slavish adherence to "rule of thumb"s.

Comment: I'm sorry but your statement about not setting arrays to null is invalid here. The code given by the OP clearly shows the intent, which I don't think you caught on to. Hence: don't rely on rule of thumbs. They only get you in trouble. The best result is not what you think here.